# Adding buttons to a Tool Window Title bar

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How Can I add another button on the Title Bar of the Tool Window next to the close window button?

For instance having an Auto Hide and Window Position buttons you see in visual studio Tool windows.

Comment: Are you using WPF, as well? Or just C#?

Comment: Just C#, but I need it in a free floating window so if I can't do it with C# I suppose I can mix in a WPF window in my app?

Comment: yes you can mix in a WPF window in your application if you sure clients have .net3.5 istalled, see http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms

Comment: I'm totally new to WPF. If I would go that route, how would I add the extra buttons to the title bar in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it can be done more elegantly with pure C#, but normally I use a window with the border style set to none and make my own mock title bar using standard buttons that look like a normal Windows title bar.  It's a bit hackey, but when I really need something like this it's the simplest approach.